# Twilio New Requirements for A2P 10DLC Registrations

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We are not prepared to persist customer's EIN's in our systems because of the associated risks and liabilities.  Does Twilio have any alternatives for registering our low-volume customers?  For example, an API that our web page could interact with for our customers to register themselves?

Is there perhaps an alternative path?  For example, creating sub-accounts for each of our hundreds of customers that would allow them to register on Twilio and still allow our software to interact with SMS on their behalf?

Are there any third party apps that Twilio endorses that could assist in the SMS registration for us?  Or even perhaps a third party API that persists encrypted data like EINs for us and assumes that liability for us?

Thanks.

Update: I realized we have options to pursue for registration without needing to persist sensitive data like their EIN.  We could inject user interaction in the middle of our current registration steps, meaning the registration steps stop at the required points in the process, our user is notified of needed data, then the registration resumes when they furnish the data.  The data like EIN would be transferred directly to Twilio API without being persisted on our server.  Problem solved.  Still, it would be good to know if there are any good answers to my other questions.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Our Messaging Product Lead says they are not aware of any 3rd party apps that help with 10DLC registrations and believe the best option is what you mentioned in your update!

Comment: @RJBreneman which strategy you adopt for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if your customers have an EIN (aren't like an independent contractor or anything), they will need to provide it to get registered on A2P 10DLC